# How to access webcam from VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, macbook-pro, webcam

I have installed windows XP on Apple MacBook Pro using VirtualBox. Here I want to access webcam from installed windows XP using VirtualBox. Is it possible? If yes, How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your webcam is connected with USB, you can connect from Windows XP.

1. Confirm your virtual machine settings that `Enable USB Controller` is checked.
2. Start your virtual machine.
3. Follow your menu `Device` -> `USB Device` and you will find your webcam.

Comment: Im using MacBook Pro laptop. It already having Web Cam. I need to access that web cam. How to do?