# My VirtualBox virtual machine freezes, when I try to use the webcam

Tags: virtualbox, webcam

I'm using a hp ElteBook 8540w with Windows 7 x64 as host and a Windows 7 x64 virtual machine running inside.

I added the webcam to to the usb filter:

[image]

carefully [terminated Skype](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/QUIT-SKYPE-Menu-Selection/m-p/91970/message-uid/91970/highlight/true#U91970) ( 1 off the 4 mentioned ways works for me ) in the host to avoid accessing it the webcam.

Activated the usb device in the VM:
[image]
[image]

When I click the allow button on http://www.testwebcam.com/
[image]

The blue led by the webcam goes on and the VM freezes and can't be killed by taskmanager ( cf. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/241295/cannot-end-windows-7-process-even-tried-pskill) )

From this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/367479/how-to-access-webcam-from-virtualbox) I guess, that it is possible in some cases to use the webcam from inside the VM, but I didn't find out how to do it on my machine.

**Edit:**

Meanwhile I tried the same with an Ubuntu guest and have exactly the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a reported problem with no known solution. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9275